# intellij println declaration

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to use ''sout'' keyword in intellij for calling system.out.println() quickly but it seems like doesnt work.
Looks like, I have some problems in settings sections.
Does anyone know the way the quick way problem

It Looks like this:
I solved the problem it was all about defining println() inside a method.

[image: It Looks like this]

I solved it. The solution is that declaring the println() method within class or
inside another method as well.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {   
             System.out.println(fun());
    } 
  
    int fun()
    {
      return 20;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah just use it inside in any method, like this:

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 1):

According to [Intellij support question](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002481400-when-typing-the-shortcut-sout-tab-i-sometimes-get-println-and-sometimes-printlf)

> Make sure you are inside the method where this completion makes sense, not just inside the class.

Comment: we are talking about different things I think

Comment: @burakzbc The question linked itself doesn't match yours, but the suggestion quoted by limido does: you are trying the completion immediately in a class, but an expression like `System.out.println(...)` is not valid in that context, so the completion is not offered. Do it in a method (or a static or instance initializer, or a constructor).